# loopback reference to a model

Tags: model, loopbackjs

I'm trying to reference a model in a beforeSave function of another model, using this documentation: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Advanced+topics%3A+models and it doesn't seem to work. Em I missing something, can someone help?

```
(model1.js)

var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

module.exports = function (Model1) {

  Model1.beforeSave = function (next, obj) {
    if (obj.relation()) return next();

    console.log(app.models.Model2);

    //next();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the "relation" part of your sample, here's what your code should look like...

```
module.exports = function (Model1) {

  Model1.beforeSave = function (next, obj) {
//    if (obj.relation()) return next();

      console.log(Model1.app.models.Model2);
          // or
      console.log(Model1.app.models('Model2'));

      next(null, obj);  // "null" = "no error". And you may have modified obj above in some way
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not access the `app` variable directly in Model1.js, you need to access it through

```
Model1.app
```

through Model1.app you will get the instance of app, and then you can call any method for it.

(model1.js)

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

module.exports = function (Model1) {

  Model1.beforeSave = function (next, obj) {
    if (obj.relation()) return next();

    console.log(Model1.app.models.Model2);

    //next();
  }
};
```